# Method for finding the number of matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ whose determinant is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I just came across a question which asks to find all the $2 \times 2$ matrices in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ whose determinant is $1$. I know that since there are only three elements in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, it is feasible to work out the problem by counting the number of correct combinations of elements. (And, though I'm not sure about my calculations, I think the answer is $20$.)

But what if there were more elements to be looked into? Then surely this pathological process wouldn't come very handy. So my question is...

> Is there any shorter method for finding out the answer of this question which also works well in other (general) cases?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First count the number of matrices with non-zero determinant. Do it column by column: the first column can be any non-zero vector, so that gives you $3^2-1$ possibilities. The second column can be any vector that does not lie in the span of the first (the determinant is 0 if and only if the two columns are linearly dependent), so you have $3^2-3$ possibilities for the second column. So that's 8*6=48 matrices with non-zero determinant.

Now, the determinant function is a surjective group homomorphism from the group of all invertible matrices to $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^\times$, so its kernel has size equal to the size of the domain / size of the image, i.e. 48/2=24.

This works in complete generality: the number of invertible matrices in $M_k(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ ($p$ a prime number) is
$$
(p^k-1)(p^k-p)(p^k-p^2)\cdots (p^k-p^{k-1}),
$$
and the number of matrices with determinant 1 is therefore that divided by $p-1$.

Comment: That's a brilliant way of doing it. Thanks a lot for helping me out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $A_i$ be the set of matrices with determinant $i$.

1. Show that $|A_i| = |A_j|$ for $i,j \neq 0$
2. Show that $|A_0| = 3^3+3^2 - 3$.
3. Show that $\sum |A_i| = 3^4$.

This works for all primes, and becomes a faster way to count the number of matrices.